# print result from data base via php

Tags: php

i'm trying to get list o user online in mydatabase :

```
public function get_list() {                 
        try {   
            $query = $this->cn->prepare("select username from user where connect = 1"); 
            $query->execute();  
            $result = $query->fetchAll();   
            return $result;     
        }catch(PDOException $ex) {  
            echo $ex->getMessage();  
        }
```

and then print this result in controller  :

```
$participation = new participation();
$list = new model_participation();

$participation->list_user_online($list->get_list());
```

the page of view is like this :

```
public function list_user_online($list_user){
        echo "<div id='content'>
             <div id='list_user_online'><h2>list_user_online</h2>";

         foreach ($list_user as $data) {

            echo "<tr><td>$data[0]</td></tr>";
        }


echo "</div>";
    }
```

the problem that in it show the result like this : user1user2user3
in fact i want print it like this : user1 
                                    user2
                                    user3

please help me ,
and thank you .

Comment: What are `<tr>` tags doing without `<table>` tag ?

Comment: Use normal view for HTML table: `<table><tr><td></td></tr></table>`

Comment: This looks more like a styling question if the user names _really_ should be output as table cells. Take a look at the table cells margins and paddings then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you code like this:

```
public function list_user_online($list_user){
        echo "<div id='content'>
             <div id='list_user_online'><h2>list_user_online</h2>";
          echo "<table><tr>";
         foreach ($list_user as $data) {

            echo "<td>$data[0]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";

   echo "</div>";
    }
```

or use css to style your div-s :-)

Comment: yes it work now with :  echo "<table>";   
         foreach ($list_user as $data) {
             
            echo "<tr><td>$data[0]</td></tr>";
        }
         echo "</table>";

Comment: I thought you want to get horisontal list , if you use echo "<tr><td>$data[0]</td></tr>"; you will got vertical listing of names.

Answer (score 0):

use `echo "<tr><td>$data[0]&nbsp;</td></tr>";`